# Logic required on how to store display multiple rows of same information

Tags: java, oracle

I have a class named passenger which will contain the details of the passenger like ticket no ,travel route,Meal selected , food selected .For cases where the passenger will be taking multiple flights the ticket no will remain the same .
So for that case i need to display one row of passenger info,followed by meal & food selections and next row with only meal & food selections for the second flight.

I get the result from database in the following format

```
Tkt Id  | Travel route | Meal selected 1 | Food selected 1
Tkt Id  | Travel route | Meal selected 2 | Food selected 2
```

I need to display in the following format

```
TKT ID | Travel route | Meal selected 1 | Food selected 1

                      | Meal selected 2 | Food selected 2
```

If there are no duplicates allowed , i can check whether the list contains the tkt id .If yes i will just append the meal selected 2 .If No , i will add the whole row.

But in this case , i am not sure on how to store and display the values as per my requirement.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I dont understand the point here to downvote the question .I have shared the scenario and my question clearly points out that i am looking for the logic and not the actual code.Also if you have downvoted , it would be better if you explain the reason for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a map e.g.

```
Map<String, List<Passenger>> routes = new HashMap<>();
for(Passenger passenger : passengers) {
    if(routes.containsKey(passenger.getId()) {
        List<Passenger> route = routes.get(passenger.getId());
        route.add(passenger);
    } else {
        List<Passenger> newRoute = new ArrayList<>();
        newRoute.add(passenger);
        routes.put(passenger.getId(), newRoute);
    }
}
```

and print them by looping the maps values

```
for(List<Passenger> route : routes.values()) {
    System.out.print(route.get(0).getId() + " | " + route.get(0).getRoute());
    for(Passenger passenger : route) {
        System.out.println(passenger.getMeal() + " | " + passenger.getFood());
    }
}
```

Note that I havn't tried to run the code so you might need to fix some of it yourself.